# VLOOKUP to Nearest Value in Table

Tags: excel, function, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

There have been some answers regarding this subject, but none seem to be robust enough with the introduction of new data.

I have a table of values, along with an x, and z axis. The values in the middle represent the 3rd axis which form a surface plot (just additional information), y as seen in the image below:

[image]

Cell P3 has the following formula to attempt to find the nearest value, y within the table of values.

```
=VLOOKUP(O2,C2:L12,1,TRUE)
```

It incorrectly locates a value which on observation is not the nearest value.

My question is, is there a more robust way of finding the nearest value given an input O3.

Additionally, once that value has been located. Would it be possible to find the corresponding z-axis value (values in green), which aligns to the located value from VLOOKUP?

This is a mock-up to illustrate my request:

[image]

Many thanks,

Comment: You misunderstand how `VLOOKUP` works.  It is, in fact, returning the first value in the first column of lookup_range that is equal to or greater than lookup_value. Perhaps you want to include column B?

Comment: You cannot use TRUE for an approximate match on unsorted data.

Comment: Very easy with `MATCH()` and `INDEX()` ............... would you consider this alternative approach ???

Comment: Is 0.348 not the closest? Or are you also using the x value too to find which column to look in?

Comment: Hi Jerry, so the search needs to occur in the same column as the value of x. In this case, it's 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use index + match. Vlookup/Hlookup is for when you have an array with only 2 axis

here's an example of how to do it:

[image]

the formula I used to get the Z value: 
=INDEX(B3:G8,MATCH(J5,B3:B8,0),MATCH(I5,B3:G3,0))